# I am getting values in for loop. It is getting crashed

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray

I am getting values from and Array[String:Any] type array in a for loop but it is getting crashed when going on first line in for loop .

Actually I have created an array (Array[String:Any]) Type and now I am getting all the values of this array to show on tableview but it is getting crash in for loop.

```
var ticketArray = [Any]()
var addTypeTicket = [String:Any]()
var imagesArray = [Any]()
var imagesFinal = [String:Any]()


let ticketDetails = ["ticketName":txtTicketName.text!,
                     "numberOfTicketOnSale":txtFldTotalQuantityofTicket.text!,
                     "ticketPrice":txtFldPriceofTicket.text!,
                     "messageForTicketBuyers":txtviewMessage.text!,
                     "ticketGroupName":txtFldGroupName.text!] as [String : Any]

ticketArray.append(ticketDetails)
print(ticketArray)
addTypeTicket["addTypeTicket"] = ticketArray
print(addTypeTicket)
viewShadowTicket.isHidden = true
viewForMainTicketAlert.isHidden = true

for alltickets in addTypeTicket {
    let ticketName = (alltickets as AnyObject).object(forKey: "ticketName") as! String
    let Quantity = (alltickets as AnyObject).object(forKey: "numberOfTicketOnSale") as! String
    let ticketPrice = (alltickets as AnyObject).object(forKey: "ticketPrice") as! String
    let arr = structTickets(ticketName: ticketName, numberOfTicketOnSale: Quantity, ticketPrice: ticketPrice)
    self.arrayTickets.append(arr)
}
self.tableview.reloadData()
tableview.isHidden = false
```

I just want to get values in for loop .

Comment: What crash? Can you show the output?

Comment: you are using ! sign a lot, what you expect?, you are forcing unwrapping on values that maybe are null that is why your app is crashing

Comment: You're using forced unwrapping too much unnecessarily. Avoid that. It'll result in the crash even for a single mistake.

Comment: Are you sure all those values are of String type ?

Comment: `alltickets as AnyObject`(bridge cast to `NSObject`) is horrible syntax. Actually `ticketDetails` is `[String:String]`and therefore `ticketArray` is  `[[String:String]]`. Never use `Any` if the actual type is known and unique.

Comment: @SharadChauhan yes all the keys are in string

Comment: @vadian So what I will use to get values from (addTypeTicket) this array

Comment: `addTypeTicket` is a dictionary, not an array. Your code is a bit confusing anyway.

Comment: Which array you are using to populate your tableView ? Are you using ticketArray and addTypeTicket anywhere else too?

Comment: So can anyone tell me how I will create [String:Any] to NSArray

Comment: And why do you want to do that ? In the end what you want to achieve ? You just need ticketName and other data so that you can show them in your tableView ?

Comment: @SharadChauhan  addTypeTicket array I am using.

Comment: `addTypeTicket` is not an `Array` as pointed by vadian already.

Comment: @SharadChauhan can you please tell me from which array I will count in numbeofRowinSection

Comment: @SharadChauhan OMG Sharad Thanks man got the point. Nice Clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using `ticketArray` anywhere else then there is not need to add data to that array. You can simply add data to `addTypeTicket` dictionary by:

```
addTypeTicket["addTypeTicket"] = ticketDetails
```

Then you can fetch the data like this:

```
if let addTypeTicketData = addTypeTicket["addTypeTicket"] as? [String: String] {
    let ticketName = addTypeTicketData["ticketName"]
    let quantity = addTypeTicketData["numberOfTicketOnSale"]
    let ticketPrice = addTypeTicketData["ticketPrice"]
    let arr = structTickets(ticketName: ticketName, numberOfTicketOnSale: quantity, ticketPrice: ticketPrice)
    self.arrayTickets.append(arr)
}
```

And use `arrayTickets` for `tableView's numberOfRowsInSection`.